# Correct map settings with Tiled For Iphone

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

So i am using tiled to create levels for my new iphone game.

The when creating a map with tiled for iphone the correct map size is 50x50 and tile size 32x32.

The problem is with these dimensions the tiles are to small for what i need it for.

So i have tried doubling the settings to map size 100x100 and tile size 64x64 but no luck..

Anyone familiar with doing this?

The goal is i would like the tiles to be bigger and take up more of the screen space. If you dont get the settings right, the map wont show up correctly on the screen half of it will be hanging of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two things to consider: the size of your tiles must match the tile size setting in Tiled, otherwise they will not align correctly. If you double tile size to 64x64 you also have to double the size of the tileset image.

The other thing is how many tiles fit on the screen. If you divide 480 by 64 you get 7.5 meaning 7 and a half tiles fit on the screen on the horizontal direction (assuming landscape mode). If that's what you need, you'll have to make sure the tile size is clearly divisible by 480x320 respectively 1024x768 on iPad or 568x320 on widescreen devices.